# Format Phone Numbers In SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2008 and I found this solution which is only for SQL Server 2012 - what is the equivelant to format a phone number in SQL Server 2008?

```
FORMAT([PhoneField],'###-###-####')
```

Comment: There isn't one (and FORMAT() isn't a bowl of ice cream either - lots of overhead). Why do you need to format phone numbers in T-SQL? This is a job better handled by the presentation tier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there isn't a function that will do it for you. You can cast the phone number as a string then then parse out the parts and add hyphen

```
declare @phone int
set @phone = '1232223333'
select SUBSTRING(cast(@phone as varchar(10)),1,3)+'-'+SUBSTRING(cast(@phone as varchar(10)),4,3)+'-'+SUBSTRING(cast(@phone as varchar(10)),7,4)
```

Comment: I would assume that `PhoneField` is a varchar, not an int.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming that the [PhoneField] is 10 digits, such as '1234567890' then you could use STUFF to put the proper values in.  E.g.

```
select STUFF(STUFF('1234567890',7,0,'-'),4,0,'-');
```

But please note that this only answers formatting a phone number for the 10-digit answers.  If you are using internationally dialed numbers, you need to investigate the various forms of phone numbers you might need to handle.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_conventions_for_writing_telephone_numbers